# Why doesn't Power BI allow me to implement incremental refresh on appended table?

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI pbix file. There is what I do in the editor.

Fetch data from sql table1

Fetch data from sql table2

Append the above to create table3

At this point:

1. For table 1 and 2 should I choose `enable load`, and `include in report refresh`?
2. Why is there no option to configure incremental refresh for tavke 3?

Answer (score 0):

Do not enable load on Query 1 and 2, and reference the RangeStart and RangeEnd parameters in Query 3.  You don't have to *actually use* the parameters to filter in Query 3; you can do that in Query 1 and 2.

Comment: In the UI when I configure Incremental refresh, I have to do it on table3 because table1 and table2 won't show up. But you are saying that the rangestart/end params on table1 and table2 will still work?

Comment: Yes, should work.